# Path 404 issue loading js files in jsp/servlet

Tags: jsp

[image]

This is the structure inside the project.

What i want is load the js files to the html file

this is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Third App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-                scalable=no"/>
    <!--  <link href="/ThirdApp/WebContent/lib/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

    <script src="/ThirdApp/WebContent/lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/ThirdApp/WebContent/lib/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>HOME</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <!--<a href="02_menuform.html" data-role="button">MENU</a>-->
            <a href="/FirstApp/jsp/menu.jsp" data-role="button">MENU</a>
            <a href="02_busform.html" data-role="button">BUS</a>
            <a href="02_restaurantform.html" data-role="button">DELIVERY CONTACT</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think the path is correct. However, if i run the app, it throws 404 not found. which means the path is wrong i think.

Comment: huh? something is weird. <link href="../../lib/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> i added the code like this and the request url is http://localhost:8080/ThirdApp/lib/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css

Comment: this works. but this is a different structure to the comparing to the existing one?! what is going on in here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you should not keep scripts in the lib folder. Move all your scripts to another folder. It can be `WebContent/scripts/`. Put all `.js` files there. Then in `jsp` use `jstl`:

```
<script src='<c:url value="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>'></script>
```